# I can't connect Netezza with microsoft ODBC (VS 2013)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, netezza

I install netezza ODBC drivers and configure data sources(ODBC) in Adminitstrative tools by add user DSN as NZSQL.

Next I connect with Visual studio 2013 using DSN in Server Explorer, in Datasource I select Microsoft ODBC data source and data provider I select .Net framework data provider for ODBC. The connection test is successful and I copy connectionstring from connection string in server explorer and paste it in web.config:

```
<add name="cn" connectionString="Dsn=NZSQL;Driver={NetezzaSQL};uid=kbanke2e"/>
```

When I compile the error is:

> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
>   not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server

Comment: You might want to state what the error is.

Comment: I add the error already

Answer (score 1):

I successfully managed to create a Netezza datasource in VS2013 by specifying the full connection string manually:

```
Driver={NetezzaSQL};server=a.b.c.d;port=5480;database=SYSTEM;uid=myname;password=mypwd;
```

The only problem I had was due to VS looking for the 32-bit driver (`nsqlodbc.dll`) in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`. Initially I only had the 64-bit driver installed.